# How to enable interrupt function in sw4stm32

Tags: timer, interrupt, stm32, isr

I use  SW4STM32 toolchain,I want to bliking led using timer2 when overflow, in STM32103RET,
here is my functions to turn led on and of.

```
void TurnOnLed(){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_SET);
}

void TurnOffLed()
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

the timer2 initilizing has been set by stm32 cube mx, but i do not know which function called when timer2 overflows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to start your timer by function

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htimX);
```

And for the firs time implement you callback function named `HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback`:

```
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if (htim->Instance == TIMx) {
    }
}
```

If you don't know anything about HAL_Driver you may found a lot of information from:

1. [STM32F0xx HAL_Driver description](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2f/77/25/0f/5c/38/48/80/DM00122015.pdf/files/DM00122015.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00122015.pdf) or for another family just search for `HAL Driver` on st.com
2. You can see examples of HAL Driver usage (as you use CubeMX, so you can found it in `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/STM32Cube/Repository/` directory)
3. Just open `stm32f?xx_hal_tim.c` and see what functions are present, see their comments to uderstand what tey are doing. And see what functions are called from `HAL_TIM_IRQHandler` to know how are named callbacks.

Comment: Hi @imbearr I do like what you say but HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback still not executed,why?

Comment: @daotian, Depend on way that you have created your initalization code. If you do not use STMCubeMX software - see for example more expanded answer by zahra bellow. I think your ploblem in last section of him answer. Otherwise: if you are use STMCubeMX, or in case if all advices are not help - you must check with debugger: peripheral clocking registers, NVIC registers, timer registers config and state (are it run? and what period, and etc.)...

Comment: @I checked and when I executed onece and stop the Tim how to start it again?

Comment: @daotian same way as start

Comment: @daotian, this depend on what you use for  stop/start and what behaviour you expect. Generally if you use HAL or SPL library and understand what you doing - nothing bad. Please read "Reference Manual" (from st.com) to understand what really happen in your firmware.

Comment: To say the truth. I am not so patient to read it and I am seeking a way to make myself patient.

Comment: @daotian, this one important thing that make differ engineers - they read to know, because knowledge is pleasure for they. Read reference manual by parts, that interesting for you at this time - it's will be more easy and needs you patient less.

Answer (score 3):

First,You have to configure your timer:

```
/* TIM2 init function */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_SlaveConfigTypeDef sSlaveConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 10000;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 1000;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sSlaveConfig.SlaveMode = TIM_SLAVEMODE_RESET;
  sSlaveConfig.InputTrigger = TIM_TS_ITR0;
  if (HAL_TIM_SlaveConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sSlaveConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  }
```

Second use this function to handle interrupt:

```
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_10);
     __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim2, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE);            //clear interrupt flag
    //HAL_Delay(500);
}
```

Do not forget enable interrupts in main() function:

```
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 1);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);// Enable interrupt from TIM3 (NVIC level)
```